# Denying user permission that haven't completed the checkout process with stripe subscription

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

So, I followed a tutorial on Youtube on how to set up a Stripe subscription. I have the keys inserted correctly and the sign up form etc. all set up. The only problem is that I noticed that if the user doesn't pay and goes back to the home page, they'll be able to see everything. What's the best way to deny their access until they have completed payment?

Currently my subscriber controller is this

```
class SubscribersController < ApplicationController

before_filter :authenticate_user!

def new
end

def update
token = params[:stripeToken]


customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
  card: token,
  plan: 1020,
  email: current_user.email
)

@user = User.find(current_user.id)
@user.subscribed = true
@user.stripeid = customer.id
@user.save

redirect_to people_path, notice: "Welcome"
end

end
```

Registration Controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
protected

def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    '/subscribers/new'
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an additional before_filter method if you don't want non-paying customers to be able to access the application. This will likely require you creating an additional boolean field on your users table, something like "paid" and using that as your filter. Example...

```
class SubscribersController < ApplicationController

before_action :authenticate_user!
before_action :authenticate_payment

def new
end

def update
token = params[:stripeToken]


customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
  card: token,
  plan: 1020,
  email: current_user.email
)

@user = User.find(current_user.id)
@user.subscribed = true
@user.stripeid = customer.id
@user.save

redirect_to people_path, notice: "Welcome"
end

private

def authenticate_payment
  @user = User.find(current_user.id)
  unless @user.paid? 
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

EDIT: if you already have a subscribed field for the user, that is marked as true when payment is confirmed then a filter like this should work

```
def authenticate_subscription
  @user = User.find(current_user)
  unless @user.subscribed?
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

Comment: Yeah I already have that, it's a boolean for subscribed. I'll try before_filter :authenticate_subscribed ?

Comment: Doesn't work, I run into an error :( I have this, class AddSubscriberAndStripeIdToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :subscribed, :boolean
    add_column :users, :stripeid, :string
  end

Comment: I'm trying to put before_filter :authenticate_subscribed , says invalid method. Tried a bunch of others just not such as @user.subscribed? doesn't work. Not sure which is the correct method to use to determine whether or not it's true.

Comment: Managed to figure my way out! Thanks your tip helped sooo much, the only problem now is that if the user isn't subscribed it gets thrown into a loop and an error page.

Comment: Can you post the full error message? Is if subscribed is boolean column on User, and your current_user method is finding the user object, it should work? Also to note, you should only put this before_filter on the controller you want to prevent non-subscribed users from viewing.

Comment: You can always teak the authenticate_subscription method to redirect to a different page. What loop/error are you getting now?

Comment: basically im trying to protect the content of my homepage (root) unless the user is subscribed. When the user isn't subscribed they get redirected and then an error page because of "too many redirects"

Comment: I'd move this to chat if I could... If you're putting this filter on your home page, you're calling redirect_to root_url every time the root_url is loaded. Because you're trying to reload the root_url each time, the redirect gets called each time, try redirecting to a different page

Comment: fixed it! i'm just redirecting them back to the payment page. You rock :) Thanks sooo much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87412/discussion-between-wilson-and-j-rhoades).